# Sql correct syntax for raw query in laravel

Tags: sql, database, laravel, controller

I have tested this query in mysql and it works.
it doesn't work in mine controller. Can anyone correct it please?

```
 $albi = DB::table(DB::raw("(SELECT
                          albi.id,
                          albi.CoverAlbo,
                          albi.Nazione,
                          albi.Editore,
                          albi.NomeCollanaUfficiale,
                          albi.AnnoPubblicazione
                          FROM albi AS a LEFT JOIN albi_user AS au ON a.id = au.albi_id
                          AND au.user_id = $user_id
                          WHERE au.albi_id IS NULL)"));
```

this is the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias

please help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're using `DB::table()` and then placing a `raw` query inside it (creating a sub query) and then not giving it an alias.

To get your above code to work you should just need to change the last line to something like:

```
WHERE au.albi_id IS NULL) as t1")); //notice the "t1" alias
```

---

Or you could `DB::select()`:

```
$albi = DB::select("SELECT
                      a.id,
                      a.CoverAlbo,
                      a.Nazione,
                      a.Editore,
                      a.NomeCollanaUfficiale,
                      a.AnnoPubblicazione
                      FROM albi AS a LEFT JOIN albi_user AS au ON a.id = au.albi_id
                      AND au.user_id = $user_id
                      WHERE au.albi_id IS NULL");
```

Please note this is not the same `select()` as `DB::table()->select()`

---

Or you could just use the the Query Builder:

```
$albi = DB::table('albi')
    ->select('id', 'CoverAlbo', 'Nazione', 'Editore', 'NomeCollanaUfficiale', 'AnnoPubblicazione')
    ->leftJoin('albi_user', 'albi.id', 'albi_user.alibi_id')
    ->where('albi_user.user_id', $user_id)
    ->whereNull('albi_user.albi_id')
    ->get();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should use alias instead of table name. So try this:

```
 $albi = DB::table(DB::raw("(SELECT
                          a.id,
                          a.CoverAlbo,
                          a.Nazione,
                          a.Editore,
                          a.NomeCollanaUfficiale,
                          a.AnnoPubblicazione
                          FROM albi AS a LEFT JOIN albi_user AS au ON a.id = au.albi_id
                          AND au.user_id = $user_id
                          WHERE au.albi_id IS NULL)"));
```